# colcon build failed on ros2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i was following this [official tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Creating-A-Workspace/Creating-A-Workspace.html)  with my raspberry pi 4. i was executing

```
colcon build
```

but every time i execute that, i get:

```
    [1.935s] WARNING:colcon.colcon_core.package_selection:Some selected packages are already built in one or more underlay workspaces:
        'turtlesim' is in: /opt/ros/humble
If a package in a merged underlay workspace is overridden and it installs headers, then all packages in the overlay must sort their include directories by workspace order. Failure to do so may result in build failures or undefined behavior at run time.
If the overridden package is used by another package in any underlay, then the overriding package in the overlay must be API and ABI compatible or undefined behavior at run time may occur.

If you understand the risks and want to override a package anyways, add the following to the command line:
        --allow-overriding turtlesim

This may be promoted to an error in a future release of colcon-override-check.
Starting >>> turtlesim
[Processing: turtlesim]
[Processing: turtlesim]
[Processing: turtlesim]
[Processing: turtlesim]
--- stderr: turtlesim
CMake Deprecation Warning at /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_target_interfaces.cmake:32 (message):
  Use rosidl_get_typesupport_target() and target_link_libraries() instead of
  rosidl_target_interfaces()
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:51 (rosidl_target_interfaces)


CMake Deprecation Warning at /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_target_interfaces.cmake:32 (message):
  Use rosidl_get_typesupport_target() and target_link_libraries() instead of
  rosidl_target_interfaces()
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:55 (rosidl_target_interfaces)


CMake Deprecation Warning at /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_target_interfaces.cmake:32 (message):
  Use rosidl_get_typesupport_target() and target_link_libraries() instead of
  rosidl_target_interfaces()
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:58 (rosidl_target_interfaces)


CMake Deprecation Warning at /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_target_interfaces.cmake:32 (message):
  Use rosidl_get_typesupport_target() and target_link_libraries() instead of
  rosidl_target_interfaces()
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:61 (rosidl_target_interfaces)


/home/pi/ros2_ws/src/ros_tutorials/turtlesim/tutorials/teleop_turtle_key.cpp: In member function ‘void TeleopTurtle::sendGoal(float)’:
/home/pi/ros2_ws/src/ros_tutorials/turtlesim/tutorials/teleop_turtle_key.cpp:200:5: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘rclcpp_action::Client<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute>::GoalResponseCallback’ {aka ‘std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> >)>’} and ‘TeleopTurtle::sendGoal(float)::<lambda(std::shared_future<std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> > >)>’)
  200 |     };
      |     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/future:47,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors.hpp:18,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:155,
                 from /home/pi/ros2_ws/src/ros_tutorials/turtlesim/tutorials/teleop_turtle_key.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:530:9: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Functor> std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Requires<std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Callable<_Functor>, std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&> std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator=(_Functor&&) [with _Functor = _Functor; _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> >}]’
  530 |         operator=(_Functor&& __f)
      |         ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:530:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/move.h:57,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from /usr/include/c++/11/memory:63,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:153,
                 from /home/pi/ros2_ws/src/ros_tutorials/turtlesim/tutorials/teleop_turtle_key.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11/type_traits: In substitution of ‘template<bool _Cond, class _Tp> using __enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if::type [with bool _Cond = false; _Tp = std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> >)>&]’:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:353:8:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Res, class ... _ArgTypes> template<class _Cond, class _Tp> using _Requires = std::__enable_if_t<_Cond::value, _Tp> [with _Cond = std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> >)>::_Callable<TeleopTurtle::sendGoal(float)::<lambda(std::shared_future<std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> > >)>, TeleopTurtle::sendGoal(float)::<lambda(std::shared_future<std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> > >)>, std::__invoke_result<TeleopTurtle::sendGoal(float)::<lambda(std::shared_future<std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> > >)>&, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> > > >; _Tp = std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> >)>&; _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> >}]’
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:530:2:   required by substitution of ‘template<class _Functor> std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> >)>::_Requires<std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> >)>::_Callable<_Functor, typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type>::type, std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> >)> >::value), std::decay<_Tp> >::type::type, std::__invoke_result<typename std::enable_if<(! std::is_same<typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<_Tp>::type>::type, std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> >)> >::value), std::decay<_Tp> >::type::type&, std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> > > >, std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> >)>&> std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> >)>::operator=<_Functor>(_Functor&&) [with _Functor = TeleopTurtle::sendGoal(float)::<lambda(std::shared_future<std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> > >)>]’
/home/pi/ros2_ws/src/ros_tutorials/turtlesim/tutorials/teleop_turtle_key.cpp:200:5:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/11/type_traits:2211:11: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> >)>&>’ 2211 |     using __enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/future:47,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors.hpp:18,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:155,
                 from /home/pi/ros2_ws/src/ros_tutorials/turtlesim/tutorials/teleop_turtle_key.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:540:9: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Functor> std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>& std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator=(std::reference_wrapper<_Functor>) [with _Functor = _Functor; _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> >}]’
  540 |         operator=(reference_wrapper<_Functor> __f) noexcept
      |         ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:540:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/home/pi/ros2_ws/src/ros_tutorials/turtlesim/tutorials/teleop_turtle_key.cpp:200:5: note:   ‘TeleopTurtle::sendGoal(float)::<lambda(std::shared_future<std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> > >)>’ is not derived from ‘std::reference_wrapper<_Tp>’
  200 |     };
      |     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/11/future:47,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/executors.hpp:18,
                 from /opt/ros/humble/include/rclcpp/rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp:155,
                 from /home/pi/ros2_ws/src/ros_tutorials/turtlesim/tutorials/teleop_turtle_key.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:469:7: note: candidate: ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>& std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator=(const std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&) [with _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> >}]’
  469 |       operator=(const function& __x)
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:469:33: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘TeleopTurtle::sendGoal(float)::<lambda(std::shared_future<std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> > >)>’ to ‘const std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> >)>&’
  469 |       operator=(const function& __x)
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:487:7: note: candidate: ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>& std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator=(std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>&&) [with _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> >}]’
  487 |       operator=(function&& __x) noexcept
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:487:28: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘TeleopTurtle::sendGoal(float)::<lambda(std::shared_future<std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> > >)>’ to ‘std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> >)>&&’
  487 |       operator=(function&& __x) noexcept
      |                 ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:501:7: note: candidate: ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>& std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator=(std::nullptr_t) [with _Res = void; _ArgTypes = {std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> >}; std::nullptr_t = std::nullptr_t]’
  501 |       operator=(nullptr_t) noexcept
      |       ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_function.h:501:17: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘TeleopTurtle::sendGoal(float)::<lambda(std::shared_future<std::shared_ptr<rclcpp_action::ClientGoalHandle<turtlesim::action::RotateAbsolute> > >)>’ to ‘std::nullptr_t’
  501 |       operator=(nullptr_t) noexcept
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/turtle_teleop_key.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/turtle_teleop_key.dir/tutorials/teleop_turtle_key.cpp.o] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:628: CMakeFiles/turtle_teleop_key.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< turtlesim [2min 29s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [2min 30s]
  1 package failed: turtlesim
  1 package had stderr output: turtlesim
```

my ubuntu version is 20.04 LTS and my ROS version is humble. what should I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412774/colcon-build-failed-on-ros2/) by [redbeet1007](https://answers.ros.org/users/140428/redbeet1007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2023-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

are you sure your `humble` runs on `20.04`?  but official suggests:

https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Install-Binary.html#system-requirements

---

Originally posted by [fury.nerd](https://answers.ros.org/users/108548/fury.nerd/) with karma: 78 on 2023-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0